# Prompt user to select a cell, get and store string from that cell

Tags: excel, vba, string, input

basically I'm trying to obtain a string from a user selected cell and store that string for later use.

Currently, I use this function many times in an existing loop. It works the first time through, and then after that it fails to work. I'd like to store the string contained within the user selected cell as a separate string variable, sCell.

```
Dim vendor As String, sCell As String

vendor = "New Test Vendor 8675309"

pInput = vendor & " does not appear in Vendor Database." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Does " & vendor & " already exist?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     "If yes, please select the Vendor Number  that " & vendor & " belongs to." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     "Otherwise, please select a cell that says " & """" & "Does not Exist" & """" & "."

sCell = Application.InputBox(pInput)
```

After I execute the macro, I get a run-time error type mismatch on the second time through. Any tippers?

Comment: hi, whats the line that throws the error ?

Comment: sCell = Application.InputBox(pInput) throws the error

Answer (score 0):

If you want a range, you should `Dim` your variable as a range

try:

```
Dim vendor As String
Dim sCell As Range

vendor = "New Test Vendor 8675309"

pInput = vendor & " does not appear in Vendor Database." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Does " & vendor & " already exist?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     "If yes, please select the Vendor Number  that " & vendor & " belongs to." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
     "Otherwise, please select a cell that says " & """" & "Does not Exist" & """" & "."

Set sCell = Application.InputBox(Prompt:=pInput, Type:=8)
```

To get the address, use `sCell.Address`, for the value, use `sCell.Value`